# Apache and PHP Error Message

Tags: server, apache2, php

I'm working on a personal project and keep getting this error message:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php on line 20

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php' (include_path='/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/pear/archive_tar:/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/html/owncloud/lib/private:/var/www/html/owncloud/config:/var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty:/var/www/html/owncloud/apps:/var/www/html/owncloud/lib:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:/var/www/html/owncloud') in /var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php on line 20
```

How do I resolve this error? i am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 and apache2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check two things

1. First file exists are not ?

what is the output of

```
ls -ltrh /var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php
```

If file exits then step 2

2. what is the permission of file

   ```
    /var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php
   ```

does it having read permissions ? 
If not do chmod 755

```
chmod 755 /var/www/html/owncloud/3rdparty/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift.php
```

If file not exists I hope you know what need to be done.

Comment: to Criticiser's I have mentioned ls -ltrh just to see permissions as well. I  know I can use ls and ls -l too. Thank you.